# Custom Property has strange IDE PropertyGrid behavior

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm using VS .NET 2010 ultimate edition. I encounter a strange behavior of some properties on my (custom) component and I'd like to know it's my problem or IDE problem. I post two images, first is before edit the property, change Dot->Size->Height from 5 to 20 and the second is after hit enter to change the new value.

[image: This is befor editing my property]

[image: And this is after edit the property and hit enter]

Now you can see the "Spacing" property (which wasn't touch) is seen doubled :)
The component acts normal, both on design time and run time, so everithing is oukey except this weird aspect. When I click at [+] sign, things revert to normal, properties are shown oukey and updated.

What's the problem ?

PS. I suspect the problem is in CreateInstance function of my TypeConverter class because when I comment those functions, properties are ok, but of course, component isn't updated anymore at design time (until I click somewhere else on a form)

Here are the functions:

```
Public Overrides Function GetCreateInstanceSupported(ByVal context As System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext) As Boolean
  Return True
End Function

Public Overrides Function CreateInstance(ByVal context As System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext, ByVal propertyValues As System.Collections.IDictionary) As Object
  Dim da As New DotAttributes With
                  {
                    .Color = CType(propertyValues("Color"), Color),
                    .Shape = CType(propertyValues("Shape"), DotShapes),
                    .Size = CType(propertyValues("Size"), Size),
                    .Spacing = CType(propertyValues("Spacing"), Size)
                  }
  Return da
End Function
```

Comment: the problem is urgent, pleas help.. thanks in advance

Comment: Try creating the smallest amount of code that reproduces the problem and add that to your post.